# Why is "else" redundant here in recursion?

Tags: python

Learning python, I got a question why "else" here is redundant and not needed

```
def print_n(s, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
**else:**
    print(s)
    print_n(s, n-1)
print_n("spam", 5)
```

Comment: Because of the `return` above it. It can't happen that the if-condition is true and the else-block is executed (with or without `else`).

Comment: When the `if` statement is true, the function exits altogether. So any code that you would put in an `else` block can just go at the main level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `else` because the `if` terminates with a `return`.

```
def print_n(s, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    print(s)
    print_n(s, n-1)

print_n("spam", 5)
```

I'm not sure that qualifies as redundant because some would like the else to be explicit, not implied. In this case its straightforward, but in the case of a more complicated if clause where the `return` isn't obvious (maybe there is a loop inside the if), one would like the `else` to be there.

Comment: Conversely, some people believe in programming without `else`. https://dgls.dev/posts/else-statement